# Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in /home/a7053783/public_html/index.php on line 1

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in
>   /home/a7053783/public_html/index.php on line 1.

How can I fix the error mentioned above?

Comment: @RobertPitt: Its most likely wordpress. In there, there are default functions like `get_header();`, `get_sidebar();` and `get_footer();` etc. Still, this question is way too vague.

Answer (score 1):

As probably you are creating your own wordpress theme. I'm so good at wordpress, but do you have `header.php` file in the same folder as `index.php` in what you call `get_header();`?
Because, if you are viewing your `index.php` theme-file on the actual homepage..then it is unlikely, that wordpress is missing the function.

Also you must make sure, that your theme's `functions.php` file is correctly filed. I cant remember anymore, what were the MOST critical aspects in the function-file. But this may very well be the problem.

You probably want to double check all of your theme-creating-steps using [this tutorial](http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/). And also let it be noted, that you can get better wordpress related answers from [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant to call the function `get_headers()`? `get_header()` is not a standard PHP function.

By the way: it is way easier to help you if you include an example of the actual code going wrong.

Comment: <?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

 <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn">

 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: Maybe `get_header` function is in other file which you don't load with `require` or `include`.

Answer (score 0):

As this error occurs in line 1 i suppose `get_header()` is not avaialbe.
But i recommend you put the code of index.php here.

Answer (score 0):

Some more code would help.

Regarding only that message I would guess that you either tryed to call `get_header()` before including the file that contains the `get_header()` function, or that you meant `get_headers()`.

Answer (score 0):

i believe this is an error in wordpress, try changing the theme, if the error goes, then you can make sure that it is the problem of the theme

Answer (score 0):

It mostly Appear because of get_header() is not checking properly
you can do it via simply adding if condition

btw read source :

http://fixmycms.com/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-get_header-in-index-php-on-line-1/

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with the latest version (3.8.1 french edition)

It is really weird but it seems to be related with your *index.php* file in the template.
Instead, create a specific file according to the template hierarchy for all the views: *front-page.php, page.php, single.php*.

Refer to this link for more info about template hierarchy
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy